# Algorithm for associating vertices using mesh topology

Tags: algorithm, mesh, vertices, topology

I have two meshes (head models, to be precise) with the same topology (number of vertices and arrangement of triangles) but different vertex positions and, crucially, different vertex orders and triangle orders.

I want to be able to use the vertex data of one as a morph-target for the other, which means finding the unique vertex Bj in model B that corresponds to each vertex Ai in model A.

I can't use position as the models are different shapes. I can't use vertex order because it's different - same with triangle order. What I need is a way of using the mesh topology to create a vertex-to-vertex association. Does anyone have such an algorithm to hand?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any specific topological features (holes, ...) you can use to create correspondences for a small number of vertices, edges or faces?
I'm not sure I can give you a specific algorithm, but my first idea would be to use a guided approach - you select equivalent edge loops in both meshes and extend them to equivalences of neighboring faces by extending your correspondence mapping in a BFS fashion inwards, employing a backtracking approach to decide ambiguities based on their neighborhood information. Since most large meshes are rather regular, this heuristic might work well.

Comment: If you can extract unique topological "signatures" for each vertex, then you can model this as an Assignment Problem (specify a positive profit for matching two vertices with equal signatures, and a negative profit for matching two vertices with different signatures) and solve it with the Hungarian Algorithm in O(n^4) time.  I would suggest first using vertex degrees (neighbour counts) as signatures; if that screws up, build a vector where the first component is the degree and the second component is the number of other vertices at distance 2, etc.

Comment: Thanks, both of you. I think extending edge loops is a better way forward here as O(n^4) is going to take a long, long time :)

Comment: How far "apart" (in a morphological sense) are these heads? And can you tell if head B e.g. is upside down and the eyes have switched position?

Comment: Far enough, given the density of the mesh, for any kind of best guess derived from proximity to go wrong. They might also be at different angles - maybe not upside down. Eyes aren't a problem as they're separate meshes.

Comment: Ok, another try: how would one distinguish a chin in A from the forehead in B? If I get you right, you have two wobbly orbs and no discernible feature that could connect them?

Comment: PS: please include an @_username_ in your comments, otherwise they don't show up in the users inbox.

Comment: @Vroomfondel I think you're trying to solve a much, much trickier problem than I am :) When I say mesh topology, don't think about eye holes and mouth holes; imagine every triangle poly is a hole. The polygon data order and vertex data order can be different, as well as the vertices being in different positions, but the actual structure of the mesh is the same. One is a deformation of the other, vertex for vertex, edge for edge.

Comment: I get that as "first head is Heidi Klum, second is Arnold Schwarzenegger" - you mean that both of them are staring upright in the same direction? Because if both are floating around in space, no one could tell how to morph one into the other.

Comment: @Vroomfondel Yes, you can, if the polygonal topology of the two heads is identical.

Comment: @Vroomfondel Take a simple example: three triangles connected together thus: ABC/BCD/CDE. Now suppose you have another shape which also consists of three connected triangles: PQR/QRS/RST. Even if those triangles are somewhere else in space; even if you randomise the letters PQRST (vertex order) and randomise the polygon order (eg RST/PQR/QRS), there's still a unique, identifiable vertex-to-vertex mapping between the two shapes that preserves the three-triangle-two-shared-edges topology. The challenge is to find that mapping.

Comment: Ok. For a solution one is however dependent on the existence of certain topological features. There are meshes which don't have such a feature - e.g. an tetrahedron. Is there an academical name for your problem, and papers about it? Sounds interesting.